# Make Org report: "Bob's 21st birthday" like imported diary entries do

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, diary

When you have:

```el
(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)
```

set, then an entry in the `~/diary` file like this:

```
%%(org-anniversary 1950 02 14) Bob's %d%s birthday
```

displays as:

```
Diary:    Bob's 65th birthday
```

in the Org agenda.

How do I get the same effect - reporting the number of repetitions whether it be measured in years or days or whatever - using normal Org syntax in an `.org` file so that I can also take advantage of other Org features such as TODOs etc?

None of the following expand the `%d` or `%s`:

```
* Bob's %d%s birthday
  <1950-02-14 Tue +1y>

* Bob's %d%s birthday
  <%%(org-anniversary 1950 02 14) Bob's %d%s birthday>

* Bob's %d%s birthday
  <%%(org-anniversary 1950 02 14)> Bob's %d%s birthday
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a chapter on [the weekly/daily agenda](http://orgmode.org/manual/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html) in the `org-mode` manual that tells you how to do this (modified for brevity; emphasis mine):

> If you are using the diary only for sexp entries and holidays, it is
>   faster to not use `(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)`, but instead to copy or even move the entries into an Org file.  Org mode evaluates diary-style sexp
>   entries, and does it faster because there is no overhead for first
>   creating the diary display.  **Note that the sexp entries must start at
>   the left margin**, no whitespace is allowed before them. For example,
>   the following segment of an Org file will be processed and entries will
>   be made in the agenda:
>
> ```
> * Birthdays
> %%(org-anniversary 1956  5 14) Arthur Dent is %d years old
> %%(org-anniversary 1869 10  2) Mahatma Gandhi would be %d years old
> ```

For your specific example, you need to do:

```
* Bob's birthday
%%(org-anniversary 1950 02 14) Bob's %d%s birthday
```

This entry will show up in the agenda as follows:

```
Week-agenda (W07):
Monday      9 February 2015 W07
...
Saturday   14 February 2015
  birthdays:  Bob's 65th birthday
...
```

### Additional info

I found this information by

1. Accessing the `org-mode` manual via

   <kbd>C-h i</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> `org mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>
2. Searching the manual for occurrences of `org-anniversary` via

   <kbd>C-s</kbd> `org-anniversary` <kbd>C-s</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> ...