# org-anniversary entries not appearing in Agenda

Tags: org-mode

What would prevent `org-anniversary` entries from appearing in the Agenda? Entries such as:

```
%%(org-anniversary 2015 01 01) New Year's Day
```

fail to show in the Agenda. I have toggled `org-agenda-include-diary` FWIW.

Update: Using Org 9.0.4:

- I have ensured that the `%%` starts flush on the left margin.
- I have tested the anniversary entry under a `*` and `**` headline.
- I have included the `PROPERTIES` drawer, as included in some example.
- I have  replaced the leading `0` characters in the dates with a space.

None of the above solved this -- the anniverary does still not appear in the agenda.

Starting Emacs with `-Q` and then evaluating only `setq org-agenda-files` ... to set my agenda file also doesn't result in the anniverary appearing in the agenda.

Including `%%(org-calendar-holiday)` results in those holidays appearing in the agenda.

Comment: Here is a link to a related thread regarding `org-anniversary` -- perhaps something in there can guide you towards a proper setup.  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7869/2287

Comment: Where is the entry? Is it in the diary or in .org file?

Comment: In a .org file.

Comment: Well if you want to use `org-anniversary` in org-mode, you don't need `org-agenda-include-diary` anyways, right? That's only if you wanted to use `org-diary-file`

Comment: @lawlist: Thanks, but nothing there solved this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why diary entries in agenda files don't work as indicated in [the info page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manua/html_node/org/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html) (by my reading).

I'm using this to regenerate a temporary `diary-file` before each viewing of the agenda.

```lisp
(defun read-lines (filePath)
  "Return a list of lines of a file at filePath."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents filePath)
    (split-string (buffer-string) "\n" t)))

(defun agenda-diary-entries ()
  "List the lines from org-agenda-files that belong in
diary-files."
  (let ((agenda-files 
     (if (stringp org-agenda-files)
         (read-lines org-agenda-files)
       org-agenda-files)))
    (seq-filter
     (lambda (s) (string-match "^[%][%]" s))
     (apply #'append
            (mapcar #'read-lines agenda-files)))))

(defun string-list-to-file (string-list filePath)
  "Save a list of strings as the lines in filePath."
  (with-temp-file filePath
    (mapcar (lambda (s) (insert s "\n")) string-list)))

(defun update-diary-from-agenda ()
  "Update (overwrite) the diary-file with lines from
org-agenda-files."
  (string-list-to-file (agenda-diary-entries) diary-file))

(add-hook 'diary-hook #'update-diary-from-agenda)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your agenda file(s) as a list.

```
(setq org-agenda-files '("path-to-agenda-file.org"))
```

(see docstring of `org-agenda-files`).

Answer (score -1):

The org-anniversary seems to have been abandoned.
Please try to do this:
%%(org-date 2015 01 01) New Year's Day

@andrew-swann

```
* Birthdays
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CATEGORY: Ann
  :END:
%%(org-date 2018 8 3)Arthur Dent is %d years old
```

C-c [

C-c a a

[image]

GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.11) of 2017-09-15, modified by Debian

Comment: Can you provide a demonstration of this working and give the relevant version info?

Comment: GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.11) of 2017-09-15, modified by Debian